# How to react to a psad alert?

Tags: linux, networking, security, psad

I am setting up a Linux home server and several guides recommend using psad to detect intrusion attempts. These guides explain in detail how to set up psad and receive alert emails when port scans are detected. However, they do not explain how to react to these alert emails.

When a scan happens, what should I do? If there is something I should do manually, shouldn't it be automated? After all, the security of my server shouldn't depend on my ability to pay immediate attention to it. If that's the case, what's the point of alert emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the [psad FAQs](https://cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/faq.html#scan_action):

> 3.1. What should I do if psad catches a scan against my system?
>
> Nmap is freely available on the internet and so anyone who wants to port scan your machine can, and they can do it quite effectively. However the vast majority of such scans are relatively harmless, especially if 1) the act of stopping them also allows you to detect them (this is the method employed by psad), and 2) the person running the scan is one of the k1dd13s. If you receive repeated scans from a particular IP, then you can use the whois information in the psad alert to determine who owns the IP and contact them directly (keep in mind of course that scans may be spoofed).

So, apparently, there is nothing to be done besides kindly asking the people responsible to stop.

Comment: you can safe yourself the effort of trying to contact people. I'm sure there are a few manual portscans out there, but you can assume that the **vast** majority are automated actions of botnets, and very likely not done through generic `nmap` but concretely looking for specific services and vulnerabilities.

Comment: Seconding. If you have a public IP interface there will always be access attempts by bots. Most common method is simple brute force SSH access attempt using wordlists for common usernames like `root` or `john`. You'll see a bunch of attempts from a single IP which `whois` usually identifies as belonging to some service provider in a country with not-so-strict regulations, then that IP's never seen again as the perps change the platform. Just keep your firewall up-to-date and properly configured and don't use common username/passwd combos and you're pretty much OK.